# Migrations Asp Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, migrations

Fiz um projeto primeiramente alimentando minha aplicação `ASP.Net MVC` por um banco de dados SQL Server que setei no arquivo web.config (connectionString).

Depois, seguindo com alguns cursos que fiz, comecei a usar o Migrations para atualizar as tabelas do banco de dados. 
Problema é que estou verificando que ele não está mais olhando a tabela e banco que estão setados no meu web.config. 
Fiz um teste, apaguei minha connectionstring do meu arquivo web.config e a aplicação continua funcionando e conectando com o banco sem problemas.

Não estou entendendo aonde está setado o banco e tabelas que ele está olhando, percebi que não é mais no meu arquivo web.config. Precisa saber para fazer umas verificações nos dados no banco SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você não especifica uma string de conexão, o Entity Framework cria uma internamente apontada para seu LocalDB e com o nome do banco igual ao seu `DbContext`

Procura no seu `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` uma base com o nome nesse fomato `MinhaSolucao.MinhaAplicacao.Contexts.MeuDbContext`

Comment: Consegui localizar, obrigado.

Comment: Se a resposta o fez localizar, por favor a marque como correta